# Answers that aren't based on knowledge - but on a hunch: - how to relate to them

Tags: discussion

From time to time someone thinks he knows the answer, and gives a non-based one, or one that lacks research (just like some of the answers)

There are some examples for it already on SFSE, and I want your opinion: do we delete the answer? or just downvote it?

I prefer to avoid links and names.

Answer (score 5):

I've probably been guilty of that, but more from misunderstanding the question. Personally, I go back and delete my own answer when I realize it isn't helping.

For others, I would recommend leaving a comment the first couple of times, asking for elaboration or something, giving the person a chance to improve their answer or state that it's a hunch. Hunches might work well as comments on the original question, too.

If that doesn't work, I'd probably down one it.

Comment: I generally downvote, and then add a comment. That usually gets their attention, and if they improve their answer. I remove the downvote and upvote them.

Answer (score 2):

I would not delete wrong answers, but down vote and comment why they are wrong. On the road to finding a solution, it may contribute to know what is wrong and why it is so. (Saves you from trying it out)

Or sometimes your hunch may lead others in the right direction, though they probably are better left in a comment on the question.